# Gist.github prolog syntax highlight

Tags: git, prolog, syntax-highlighting

On [gist.github](https://gist.github.com/) there are no prolog syntax highlight theme.

So what language should I choose for something really close to prolog syntax?

And, by the way, what's wrong with prolog? Is it really so unusable?

Comment: Cannot find the partial close button ('is it really so..?': sibjective argumentative, not a real question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The software behind https://gist.github.com/ uses Pygments, a Python syntax highlighter that includes support for Logtalk and thus ISO Prolog. There is already an open ticket to get not only Logtalk/Prolog but all languages supported by Pygments available for our gists:

http://support.github.com/discussions/gist/304-logtalk-support

Adding your comments to this ticket may help pushing for a fix ;-)

Answer (score 1):

How about Erlang? Since Erlang was inspired by Prolog, to a great degree, it seems to be a reasonable match, and basic highlighting seems to work reasonably well for Prolog fact expressions, at least.

Answer (score 0):

I would even dare to go with plain text (no highlight) since Prolog syntax is so simple that it's hard to imagine how useful having colored numbers or operators would be; perhaps highlighting built-in names is, so that you don't have to wander around the code in a possibly long and scarcely structured Prolog script searching for the implementation of a certain predicate, but that would not be served well by another language's syntax highlight algorithm.

I wouldn't say Prolog is unusable, just not very widespread. GitHub also interprets `.pl` files as Perl, so on its [languages page](https://github.com/languages) there is no mention of Prolog. StackOverflow itself does not highlight Prolog source code, nonetheless I find reading Prolog snippets published in questions and answers quite easy.